# How to rewrite the following line to work on .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-2.0

I'm developping an app in c#, and I was targeting net framework 4.0. On the proprieties window of my solution, I changed the target framework to `NET Framework 2.0`, but the app suddenly stopped working. It shows me the following error :

`No overload for method ToString() takes 1 argument`

The code that is causing the error :

```
  DateTime endTime;
  string endDate = get_end_date_fromDB();

  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(endDate, "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out endTime))
        {

            TimeSpan ts = endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

            label1.Text = ts.ToString("d' Jours 'h' Heures 'm' Minutes'"); // <<<< THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR

        }
```

Is there a workaround to make the code above work on C# 2.0? I need to show the date in a specific format.

Comment: @RyanGates To haze the new guy, or because you just have a sadistic team lead.

Comment: Why in 2013 would you want to target .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Older implementation does not have `ToString` override with format parameter.

```
label1.Text = string.Format("{0}' Jours '{1}' Heures '{2}' Minutes'", 
                                   ts.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes);
```

You can find .NET version specific documentation on MSDN by choosing version of interest in "other versions" combobox.

Comment: @DarrenDavies: I think you mean this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Daniel - either, I was trying to indicate the string parameter is a feature of .NET 4.

Answer (score 2):

```
label1.Text = string.Format("{0}' Jours '{1}' Heures '{2}' Minutes'", ts.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes);
```

Comment: how is this different to Anri's answer?

Comment: It's not, but we both posted at pretty much the same time; clearly I didn't see his answer before I posted mine. Although I should point out that it's not beyond the bounds of reason to look at post timestamps. ;)

Comment: @DarrenDavies it's not, most of the time questions are being answered by many people simultaneously. While you are giving one 10 others can appear

Comment: @Anri - I know how SO works, I think 3 minutes is excessive to not realize the exact same answer has been posted.

Comment: 2 minutes is excessive? I started typing the answer, then decided to actually compile the code to check that it compiled and output the correct answer, which involved starting a new instance of Visual Studio. That all easily consumed 2 minutes. Quibbling over 2 minutes like that is just... well... Do you really not have better things to do than whining about someone taking a whole 2 minutes to post something? :) (It's 2 mins, not 3 mins as you said... well it vaccilates between 2 and 3)